# woocommerce additional billing field

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add an additional field in woocommerce billing part. I want "title" field to be displayed before the "name" field.

I have tried this:

```
   // Add a new checkout field
  function custom_filter_checkout_fields($fields){
   $fields['billing_title_field'] = array(
        'some_field' => array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'required'      => true,
            'label' => __( 'Some field' )
            )
        );

    return $fields;
 }
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_filter_checkout_fields'     );
```

and then

```
   function order_fields($fields) {

$order = array(
"billing_title_field",
"billing_first_name", 
"billing_last_name", 
"billing_email",
"billing_phone",
"billing_country", 
"billing_address_1", 
"billing_address_2", 
"billing_postcode", 
"billing_company"
 );

foreach($order as $field)
{
    $ordered_fields[$field] = $fields["billing"][$field];
}

$fields["billing"] = $ordered_fields;
return $fields;
```

}

But this returns me no field I have created in the first step. I'ts clear that I'm missing a crusial part of the process, but I cannot figure out what exactly. Search on internet was no success (the methods provided there are adding fields before or after billing fields and I need to add it inside the group of billing fields).

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess I found the answer. Actually in the first piece of code I have missed an important thing. That should look like that:

```
 function custom_filter_checkout_fields($fields){
  $fields['billing']['billing_title_field'] = array(
      'some_field' => array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'required'      => true,
        'label' => __( 'Some field' )
        )
    );

return $fields;
}
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_filter_checkout_fields');
```

and then the second piece of code to set the created field to the right place.

Answer (score 1):

**add this plugin**

http://phppoet.com/docs/checkout-fields/

**and add your field you want**